# Why does Root refer to the Machine as "She", not "He"?

Tags: character, person-of-interest

[This previous question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/51102/49) about *Person of Interest* already asked why everyone else but Root called the Machine "she" rather than "it". But in this question I'm more concerned about why Root actually calls it a "she", rather than a "he". I am asking about Root because she started calling it "She" and others have simply followed the trend, as indicated by the answers to the previous question.

I understand that Root considers the Machine an intelligent being, even superior to humans. Later, she says she has an intimate relationship with the Machine. So, that helps me understand why she doesn't refer to it as "IT". Still why simply not refer to it as "He"?

Comment: My guess would be twofold. First, people who get too close with machines tend to assign them the female gender/names. We see this in cars / bikes nuts. Second, machine comes from a Latin word, machina, and that word is female (in Latin even genderless words have male and female relation). In Portuguese for example "machine" is indeed female. We'd be calling it "she" too in Portuguese, since we have no suitable "It" word. But I'd wager more on the romantic idea of a dear machine being a female (like some guys do with cars, etc)

Comment: @CyberClaw That's nice theories, but above all let's not forget that we are talking about Root. She is very female-oriented, from her childhood friendship with the real Samantha Groves whose name she took, to her advances towards Shaw, and her tries to find a replacement mother in the machine.

Comment: I may be mis-remembering, but is there not a scene where we hear the machine talking out of an ear-piece ore telephone and it's a female voice?

Comment: @Darren always (or usually) male + female prerecorded voices. But I think that when Machine talks to Root - it was never really shown what Machine says. Root refers to machine when talking to Finch as "Mom still loves us both." And it started in Stoneridge Hospital (psychiatric facility) - maybe check those scenes.

Comment: feminism possibly? root was depicted as a lesbian in the show. so feminism is my guess